# Parsing SQL XML output into multiple columns

Tags: sql

cant figure out how to separate each of the course titles into separate column rather than concatenating them into a single column?

```
--create    
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENTS_LIST(DL_ID NUMBER, D_L_XML XMLTYPE);

--insert
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENTS_LIST VALUES
(1,XMLTYPE('
   <ROW>
       <DEPARTMENT ID="1000">
          <NAME>Science</NAME>
          <COLLEGE>DIT</COLLEGE>
          <COURSES>
             <COURSE NO="2000">
                <TITLE>Computing</TITLE>
                <HOURS>20</HOURS>
             </COURSE>
             <COURSE NO="2001">
                <TITLE>Computer Science</TITLE>
                <HOURS>25</HOURS>
             </COURSE>
             <COURSE NO="2002">
                <TITLE>Networking</TITLE>
                <HOURS>30</HOURS>
             </COURSE>
          </COURSES>
       </DEPARTMENT>
    </ROW>
'));

--query
Select Dl.D_L_Xml.Extract('/ROW/DEPARTMENT/NAME/text()').Getstringval() "DEPARTMENT NAME",
Dl.D_L_Xml.Extract('/ROW/DEPARTMENT/COURSES/COURSE/TITLE/text()').Getstringval() "COURSE TITLE"
From Departments_List Dl;
```

output looks like this:

[image: output looks like this:]

Comment: Your update looks like a solution (even if not ideal). Could you please re-post it as an answer and remove it from the question? That will enable you to mark your own answer as accepted and thus close the question as solved in the unhappy event that no-one offers anything better.

Comment: Fair point, thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not ideal but this gives me something close to what I'm looking for:

```
 Select Dl.D_L_Xml.Extract('/ROW/DEPARTMENT/NAME/text()').Getstringval() "DEPARTMENT NAME",
 Dl.D_L_Xml.Extract('/ROW/DEPARTMENT/COURSES/COURSE[1]/TITLE/text()').Getstringval() "COURSE TITLE"
 From Departments_List Dl
 UNION
 Select Dl.D_L_Xml.Extract('/ROW/DEPARTMENT/NAME/text()').Getstringval() "DEPARTMENT NAME",
 Dl.D_L_Xml.Extract('/ROW/DEPARTMENT/COURSES/COURSE[2]/TITLE/text()').Getstringval() "COURSE TITLE"
 From Departments_List Dl
 UNION
 Select Dl.D_L_Xml.Extract('/ROW/DEPARTMENT/NAME/text()').Getstringval() "DEPARTMENT NAME",
 Dl.D_L_Xml.Extract('/ROW/DEPARTMENT/COURSES/COURSE[3]/TITLE/text()').Getstringval() "COURSE TITLE"
 From Departments_List Dl;
```

output:

[image]